# Data returned by ajax call is not showing up on client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request which fetches well (server side script does well) data from my database but my client side script does not show the returned data as I need. I am doing an application which should tell a user weather he is on a flooded area or not after he indicates his position on the map. I want the app say something like "Hi user, you are on a flooded area with the following characteristics...." and from the client side. See my codes below. Thanks

Server side script :

```
$prenom = $_GET['nPrenom'];
$quartier = $_GET['nQuartier'];
$long = $_GET['nLong'];
$lat = $_GET['nLat'];

$req = "SELECT type_zari FROM zari WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point($long, $lat), 4326));";
$resultat = $dbconn->prepare($req);
$resultat->execute();

while($data = $resultat->fetch()){

  if(in_array('ZARIE', $data))
              echo"Vous etes sur une zone a risque d'inondation tres eleve";
  elseif(in_array('ZARIM', $data))
              echo"Vous etes sur une zone a risque d'inondation moyenne";
  elseif(in_array('ZARIF', $data))
              echo"Vous etes sur une zone a risque d'inondation faible";
  else
    echo"Vous n'etes pas sur une zone a risque d'inondation";
}
```

Client side script which is a function called using a modal, but modal doesn't close neither when clicked on the save button:

```
function saveDataToDB(){
  var nomPrenom = document.getElementById('userName').value;
  var quartier = document.getElementById('areaSelect').value;
  var long = clickedCoord[0];
  var lat = clickedCoord[1];

  if(nomPrenom != '' && quartier != '' && long != '' && lat != ''){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getPosition.php',
      type:'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      data:{
        nPrenom: nomPrenom,
        nQuartier: quartier,
        nLong: long,
        nLat: lat
      },
      succcess: function(dataResult){
        var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
        if(dataResult.statusCode == 200){
          $('#pointadding').modal('hide');
          $(dataResult).appendTo('#map');
        } else{
          alert('Something went wrong');
        }
      }
    });
  } else{
    alert('Fill complete information');
  }
}
```

Comment: There should be an error in the console.

Comment: why would the statusCode be in the response which is clearly text. statuScode is part of the XHR object and you are not returning JSON from your server.

Comment: `$(dataResult).appendTo('#map');` - you're taking parsed JSON, trying to make it a jQuery element and then write it to an HTML element? what is this line supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Kinglish, what i want is simply having the returned data show up on a div where i have my map

Comment: You are using JSON.parse to parse a normal string.

Comment: @epascarello, what would be the right thing to do then

Comment: @HubertDjéteinboua - Can you show (in your question) what that ajax response looks like?

Comment: Just use done() and fail()

Comment: Change your success: to `success: function(dataResult) { $("#map").append(dataResult) }` - you're already in **success** so you don't need to check for statusCode (that's not there anyway) and you're returning plain text with your `echo ".."` *and* `dataType: 'html'` so no need to parse JSON.

Comment: Couple of pointers:  *always* check the console for errors / debug your values at the point of use (ie `success:function(result) { console.log(result)` / name your functions for what they do `saveDataToDB()` then calls a GET method which returns a `SELECT` - doesn't look like it saves anything to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is how you're processing the data on the client-side. The data is HTML, but you're processing it as JSON!

Looking at your PHP, it looks like the server is just returning a plain text response:

```
Vous etes sur une zone a risque d'inondation tres eleve
```

A JSON response would look more like this:

```
{
    'content': "Vous etes sur une zone a risque d'inondation tres eleve"
}
```

Both are equally valid ways of sending data from the server to the client in response to an AJAX request! But if you're going with the first, you don't need to `JSON.parse()` the response on the client-side. And if you're going with the second, you'll need to consider using a function like `json_encode()` on the server-side.

I suggest simply removing `var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);` from your JavaScript and seeing if that solves the issue!

Comment: I am still not getting what I want and again my modal doesn't close when I click on submit button, below my success code as advised : succcess: function(dataResult){
          console.log(dataResult);
          $('#map').appendTo(dataResult);
          $('#pointadding').modal('hide');

Comment: @HubertDjéteinboua Try `$('#map').append(dataResult);` instead. That appends dataResult to #map, instead of appending #map to dataResult.

Comment: i finally found that it's Content-security-policy blocking my result data to load. Thanks again

Comment: as i said my findings show that my problem is with CSP. I actually have in my DOM this : <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fetchDataFromDB()">Envoyer</button> and my function in main.js. When clicking on the button, the modal doesn't close and the returned data from server doesn't append to my div #map. How to fix then the issue of inline scripts when CSP blocks them